# gulp watch directory structure

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to use gulp to watch for changes in a directory of subfolders (think node_modules/).

I've seen a lot of documentation on watching for specific file types to be updated within a directory:

```
gulp.watch('my_folders_folder/**/*.filetype' ['some_action', ]);
```

But what I want to watch is for changes in directory structure. For example, I want to see when:

```
--my_folders_folder/
 |--folder_one/
 |--folder_two/
```

changes to:

```
--my_folders_folder/
 |--folder_one/
 |--folder_two/
 |--new_folder/
```

I don't care about what is in the folders, just whether a folder has been added or deleted. Is there a way to accomplish this with gulp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately the actual gulp version, 3.9.1 dosen't watch for new files or directories or even for deleted ones. Version 4 introduces this feature see [github.com/rehabstudio/fe-skeleton/issues/36](http://github.com/rehabstudio/fe-skeleton/issues/36) for details